# xml: copy line if tag found below that line and change content between tags from associated list or hash table

Tags: search, replace

I am rather new to emacs and need some keywords which I can than use to search the manual/forum/google.

Whenever a special tag name can be found in an xml file I would like to copy that line (tags and content between tags) to the next line below. After that the tags of that new line have to be changed, after that the content between the tags should be replaced with a value from an associated list or hash table.

original file:

```
<…….>
<………………..>
<some_tag>…….</some_tag>
  <interesting>#aAbZ_22</interesting>
     <some_tag>……..</some_tag>
  <interesting>Δ_me too !</interesting>
```

processed file:

```
<…….>
<………………..>
<some_tag>…….</some_tag>
  <interesting>#aAbZ_22</interesting>
  <newtag>#bBaZ_23</newtag>
     <some_tag>……..</some_tag>
  <interesting>Δ_me too !</interesting>
  <new_tag>Δ_ok have done</new_tag>
```

associated list or hash table:

```
key          value
#aAbZ_22     #bBaZ_23
Δ_me too !   Δ_ok have done
```

I know how to find lines with tag  CONTENT  with M-x list-matching-line and some Regex. I am also able to replace the tag names.
But what should I search for to be able to:

- copy found lines below current line
- replace content between the tags with a value from another list

I do not think that I need a hash table as the source file has less than 500 distinct values and according to the manual hash tables are useful for maaaany lines to search for. Are emacs keyboard macros powerful enough for that task or do I have to learn elisp?

Comment: I think that, because of the replacements from an association list, this problem will be quite complicated to solve with keyboard macro's only; and probably anyway will be easier to solve using lisp. You can navigate by lines using `forward-line`. copy lines using `thing-at-point`, replace content between tags using either `replace-regexp` or by using `split-string` i.c.w, `mapconcat`. To get values from an alist you can use `alist-get` (take care to set the appropriate TESTFN).

Comment: Alternatively, you could check out `libxml-parse-xml-region`, [dom.el](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Document-Object-Model.html) and [esxml](https://melpa.org/#/esxml). If you state your problem more specific, then we might be able to give more specific suggestions.

Comment: thank you dalanicolai,
I will use the input you gave me and will try to solve this :-)